# How to change arrow icon button on click with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have button icon this[image: this].. at click event i want to change it as it [image: this].. right now i am applying this code for jquery

```
<script>
   $('div[id^="module-tab-"]').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.hi').slideToggle();
   });
</sript>
```

what should  change to change left cursor arrow to right cursor arrow in jquery? please help me with code

Comment: please help me with a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) to swtich between two images. Assign each image to a `class` and switching between classes using [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) will change the image on `click`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/f72FY/2/)**

```
$('div[id^="module-tab-"]').click(function(){
     $(this).next('.hi').toggleClass("left-image right-image");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://jsbin.com/haderoyo/1/edit) is working demo of your problem

i create a active class which change background-image. 
toggling active class fullfill your requirement

here is your css

```
.tab {
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzs9m.png') no-repeat;
  padding-left:50px;
}

.tab.active {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/euD9p.png') no-repeat;
 }

.hi {
  display:none
}
```

and here is your JS

```
(function(){

  $('div[id^="module-tab-"]').click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass("active").next('.hi').slideToggle();
  });

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

hey @Jeetendra Chauhan thanx but still not get what i want.. here is anther code of html..

```
<div id="tab-module-row" style="display:none;">
    div class="module-row module-tab module-details pull-right">
      <b>Details:</b>
                                    <span class="grey-line"></span>                                                                             
          <div id="module-tab-details" class="hello-sugg">

                                        <img src="images/icons/icon-orangeboxarrow-right.png" class="right"> Some error is here                                <span class="pull-right">
                                            <img src="images/icons/icon-chat.png" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentBox">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                             <img src="images/icons/icon-alert.png">                                                 </span>
                                    </div>

                        <div class="hi" id="hi1" style="width: 95%;display:none;">
                                         <span class="grey-line"></span>    
                                <b>Suggested steps:</b><br>

                                <ol>
                                    <li>Step one to resolve the issue. Try this one first!</li>
                                    <li>Second Step to resolve the issue. Try this one first!</li>
                                </ol><br>
                                <img src="images/icons/icon-charcoalarrow.png"> <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentBox">Add Comments</a><br>
                                <img src="images/icons/icon-charcoalarrow.png"> <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#fetchData">Update / Test Data</a><br>&nbsp;<br>
                            </div>    
                                    <span class="grey-line"></span>   </div>
                            </div>
```